# Optimization in R: constrOptim contraints

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am used to working with the function `optim`, but this time I have a condition on one of my variables. I have three variables: *a*, *b*, and *d*. I don’t have any conditions on *a* or *b*, but *d* must be between 0 and 1: `0=<d=<1`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

As the constrOptim() description writes

```
The feasible region is defined by 'ui %*% theta - ci >= 0'.
```

Therefore, you need to set up a linear system of equations with coefficient matrix  'ui' and a solution vector 'ci' where'theta' denotes your variables of interest. Note that you can rewrite 'ui %*% theta - ci >= 0' as  'ui %*% theta >= ci' or multiply by a negative number to flip the inequality.

In your case, you would want to have two equations:

[image]

or

[image]

with coefficients ('ui')

[image]

and solution vector ('ci')

[image]

In **R**:

```
 ui <- rbind(c(0,0,1),c(0,0,-1))
 ci <- c(0,-1)
```

With an example from the constrOptim help file:

```
    ## from optim
 fr <- function(x) {   ## Rosenbrock Banana function
     x1 <- x[1]
     x2 <- x[2]
     100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2
 }
 grr <- function(x) { ## Gradient of 'fr'
     x1 <- x[1]
     x2 <- x[2]
     c(-400 * x1 * (x2 - x1 * x1) - 2 * (1 - x1),
        200 *      (x2 - x1 * x1))
 }
```

modified for x1<=1,x1>0

```
 ui <- rbind(c(-1,0), c(1,0))
 ci <- c(-1,0) 
 constrOptim(c(.5,0), fr, grr, ui = ui, ci = ci)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have box constraints, which can be handled natively by `optim`; you don't need `constrOptim`. Set the constraints to +/-Infinity for the unconstrained variables, and use `method="L-BFGS-B"`.

```
optim(fn, lower=c(-Inf, -Inf, 0), upper=c(Inf, Inf, 1), method="L-BFGS-B", ...)
```

Some comments:

- You might want to consider transforming `d` so that it becomes unconstrained; for example optimising over `p = log(d/(1-d))`. Unconstrained optimisation is always easier than constrained, all other things being equal.
- `optim` is actually quite old these days; try having a go with some of the other packages in the [Optimization Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/view=Optimization) on CRAN.